# How do I run priviledged javascript code from Selenium?

Tags: firefox, selenium

I'm trying to change firefox user agent string (and oscpu) without having to restart it and edit profile settings. Some firefox plugins do that, for example `user agent overrider`. Here's how it does it:

```
let UAManager = (function() {

    Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/UserAgentOverrides.jsm');

    // Orignal UA selector function, a method of UserAgentOverrides.
    // Keep it for revert to default.
    let orignalGetOverrideForURI = UserAgentOverrides.getOverrideForURI;

    let revert = function() {
        UserAgentOverrides.getOverrideForURI = orignalGetOverrideForURI;
    };

    let change = function(uastring) {
        UserAgentOverrides.getOverrideForURI = function() uastring;
    };

    let exports = {
        revert: revert,
        change: change,
    };
    return exports;
})();
```

where `Cu=Components.utils;`.

So, here's what I've tried to do:

```
        FirefoxDriver fd=new FirefoxDriver();
        fd.ExecuteScript(@"Cu=Components.utils;
            Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/UserAgentOverrides.jsm');
            UserAgentOverrides.getOverrideForURI = function() ""my user agent"";");
```

On this, I'm getting `permission denied error`. Is there any way that I can execute this script with plugin priviledges in selinum?